# How to move OVRPlayerController and OVRCameraRig together?

Tags: oculus, oculusquest

I am working on one Oculus project in that I am getting the following issue:

The OVRPlayerController is not moving along with OVRCameraRig. I am using the Unity version(2019.4.15f1) and OVRPlugin version (1.66.0).

I have added the CharacterCameraConstraint script to my OVRPlayerController but still I am getting the same issue.

Can anyone tell me how I can move the OVRPlayerController and OVRCameraRig together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can install latest unity version 2020 and import Oculus integration V34 in Unity asset store.
Create a empty scene and create plane and place OVRPlayerController over the plane.

**OVRPlayerController** : Allows the player to move around in the vitual environment.It includes components and child objects that are necessary for 3D control. It includes OVRCameraRig prefab to serve as the VR camera and is attached to a character controller.